# Blazor server side: refresh gui of after api call

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I write a server-side blazor app. You can create sensors with states (Good, warning, error...) with a little API for reporting new states.

Now I want to refetch the new state (or all sensors) on a blazor client from the DB if the API gets called.

I tried to apply "3. State Container" from this guide: https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/

How I can force the site to refetch the sensors after a API request? The Sensor and Blazor Client are different devices.

```
@inject ISensorData _db


<h1>Dashboard</h1>

@if (sensors is null)
{
    <p>Laden...</p>
}
else
{
    if (sensors.Count == 0)
    {
        <p>Keine Sensoren vorhanden!</p>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (SensorModel sensor in sensors)
        {
            <button class="btn btn-lg @StatusColor(sensor.Status) m-2">@sensor.Name @sensor.Message</button>
        }
    }
}

@code {

    private List<SensorModel> sensors;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        sensors = await _db.GetSensors();
    }

    private string StatusColor(int status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case 0:
                return "btn-secondary";
            case 1:
                return "btn-success";
            case 2:
                return "btn-warning";
            case 3:
                return "btn-danger";
            default:
                return "btn-secondary";
        }
    }
}
```

My API

```
        [HttpGet("updateState")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateState(int id, int status, string? message)
        {
            if (id <= 0)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                message = "";
            }
            try
            {
                await _db.UpdateState(id, status, message);
                //Task.Run(async () => { _dbState.CallRequestRefresh(); });
                _dbState.CallRequestRefresh();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return NoContent();
        } enter code here
```

My API Controller

```
        {
            _db = db;
            NavigationManager = navigationManager;
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("https://localhost:44346/dbRefreshHub")
                .Build();

            hubConnection.StartAsync();
        }
```

Comment: After which API is called?  I don't get the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added my API snipped. This Get Request works fine. The answer from enet is the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not entirely understand your question as it is not clearly put, and I may be missing something...

However, the State Container pattern proposed by you can't serve you in any way. It is intended to manage state for your components, etc. But I believe that you are looking for a way to notify your client side app that the "API gets called", and that it ( the client side app ) should update the new state... Am I right ?

If yes, then, I believe you can implement the SignalR Client (Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) to do that.

A while ago, I saw in one of the Blazor previews by Daniel Roths, some code snippet demonstrating how to use SignalR Client in Blazor. Search for it, or perhaps look up the topic in the docs, and see if it can offer you some remedies.

Hope this works...

Comment: Sorry about my unclear question, but you're absolutly right. thats what i'm looking for. I will looking for Dansiel Roths code snippet.

Comment: Here's it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio Note: This docs teaches you how to use SignalR client in Blazor. Learn it, and then apply it to your Blazor Server App (client-side of the app (in the browser))

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm found too. Now I try to implement it. But I don't konw how to use the NavigationManager in my API controller...

Comment: n0NamE, the way to thank an OP here is to accept his answer by clicking on the dim check sign on the left of the answer, turning it green, and by upvoting his answer by clicking on the up-arrow.  You can't and should not use the NavigationManager in your Web Api. Similarly, you shouldn't create the State Container Service and use it in your Web Api. Both are components (I'm not referring to the Blazor Component Model) of the Blazor world. The NavigationManager object is used in Blazor to enable navigation within the SPA space app as well as the outside world.

Comment: Hey enet. I accepted and upvoted your answer, but the upvote didn't count. I hardcoded the URL in the API Controller for the HubUrl, then it works just fine. So I will search futher. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The Web Api is an entity not related to Blazor at all. As you've added a Blazor Server App based on the default template, you get controllers and configurations to call end point on the existing controller, and those you may add. Usually, a Web Api is created as a separate project, and it may resides in another part of the world. No matter how you implement it (either in your Blazor Sever App or a project of its own), your Blazor client-side (in the browser) should perform HTTP calls to the Web Api endpoints in order to get data.

Comment: Unlike WebAssembly Blazor App, however, in Server Blazor the communication between the client-side and the server-side is via SignalR. You should also realize that  Blazor Server App runs on the server, and only Html diffs are passed to the client to render... again, this is done through SignaR... so you don't necessarly have to have a Web Api, and you can define a service instead.

Comment: You're right. Now I got it. I have to learn a lot more... Thanks again :)